# Implementing Photoshop High Pass Filter (HPF) in OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I need to implement a high-pass filter from Photoshop using OpenCV. I've read about high-pass filters in OpenCV and tried some kernels, like

```
[[ 0, -1, 0], 
 [-1, 4, -1],
 [ 0, -1, 0]].
```

However, the result isn't what I want to get, since the output image is mostly black-and-white while the output image in Photoshop is gray-ish. 
Here's examples:
[OpenCV high pass](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4kF2C.jpg) and 
[Photoshop high pass](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qCDxG.jpg).
Also, I tried that:

```
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(img,(ksize,ksize),0)
filtered = cv2.subtract(img,blur)
```

The result is similar to [OpenCV high pass](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4kF2C.jpg).

After that, I tried to add 127 to every pixel of the output image. Indeed, [the image look gray-ish now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tnVjh.jpg), but still it's different from the Photoshop image.

So what am I missing? Thanks in advance.

EDIT. To Håken Lid: the code now is simply this:

```
import cv2
import numpy
img = cv2.imread('input.jpg')
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(img,(31,31),0)
filtered = cv2.subtract(img, blur)
filtered = cv2.add(filtered, 127*numpy.ones(neg_frame.shape, numpy.uint8))
cv2.imwrite('output.jpg', filtered)
```

Here's [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YFCME.jpg) and [original picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I3FK2.jpg).

EDIT2. Yes, Håken Lid was right about truncating. I've edited the code once again:

```
import cv2
import numpy
img = cv2.imread('input.jpg')
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(img,(31,31),0)
filtered = img - blur
filtered = filtered + 127*numpy.ones(neg_frame.shape, numpy.uint8)
cv2.imwrite('output.jpg', filtered)
```

The output result is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dXQlQ.jpg). Now it's more like what I wanted yet the difference is still here.

my code:
[image: my output]
photoshop:
[image: photoshop output]

LAST EDIT. After playing with GaussianBlur kernel size, I've finally got what I want with `ksize = 51`. Thanks a lot for all the help! Now I'm feeling a bit dumb :P

Comment: Can you add your python code for the high pass? My guess is that negative values are truncated to 0. When you add 127, that will be the minimum value of the output. The photoshop version has output with output darker than the 127 median.

Comment: The output from your code and photoshop are very similar. I think you can get even closer by tweaking the kernel further. Photoshop might use a 5x5 kernel. Or you could try to change the 0 values to 1 and the 4 to 8  (the sum of the entire kernel should be 0).

Comment: Besides further adjusting the size of the kernel, you can also multiply the output of the difference like so: `constant * (img -blur) +127`. You’ll have to tweak until it is right.

Comment: What is `neg_frame` in your code?

Comment: Please describe your solution in an answer, to help others.

Comment: Please update with an answer containing all the code used to get your result. We don't know what `neg_frame` is, nor what it's shape is.

Answer (score 3):

If you take an image with a single white pixel on a black background and apply a filter in Photoshop, you will get a convolution kernel from Photoshop.

Comment: This is true, but here's a trick - don't use white and black, use light gray and dark gray.  Say 192 and 64.  Then you'll know what the kernel values are before clipping.

Answer (score 3):

Without unnecessary imports and variables. More Pythonic shorter way.

```py
import cv2


def highpass(img, sigma):
    return img - cv2.GaussianBlur(img, (0,0), sigma) + 127

img = cv2.imread('lena.png')
img = highpass(img, 3)

cv2.imshow('lena highpass', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

[image]

Comment: As much as I enjoy seeing Lenna, I don't think she has a place in a public forum like this.  Especially since you used a more risque version than the classic.

Comment: Search engines are open to the public and I found the uncut version of Lena from there. http://www.lenna.org/

Comment: Search engines are for people who know what they're looking for.  Nobody comes to StackOverflow looking for pictures of naked women, and probably 50% of the population will be put off by encountering it accidentally.  I urge you to consider your *whole* audience.  P.S. copyright law probably prohibits you from posting the image no matter where you found it.

Comment: i replaced it with better answer. I changed the image.

Answer (score 1):

When you are subtracting the blurred image you need to use floating points instead of integers before you add the 127, otherwise it truncate the negative pixels.
I also added an odd number checker to the kernel bit. Now it behaves like Photoshop.

```
import cv2
import numpy
img = cv2.imread('images/test.jpg')
size =50
if not size%2:
    size +=1
kernel = numpy.ones((size,size),numpy.float32)/(size*size)
filtered= cv2.filter2D(img,-1,kernel)
filtered = img.astype('float32') - filtered.astype('float32')
filtered = filtered + 127*numpy.ones(img.shape, numpy.uint8)
cv2.imwrite('output.jpg', filtered)
```